# Deploy custom labels using metadata deploy request via rest api

Tags: rest-api, deployment, metadata-api, customlabel, postman

I am trying to deploy some updates to custom labels using rest API via `metadata/deployRequest`. I found
[this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_rest_deploy.htm) in salesforce documentation. I want to invoke this rest method via powershell scripts but before I write these scripts I want to test this `metadata/deployRequest` with postman. I tried and I got errors.

For authorization I used bearer token.

In the headers I gave the content type as application/json.

In body tab I selected the zip file in form-data and I gave the deploymentOptions as raw json.

```
{ 
"deployOptions" :
    {
    "allowMissingFiles" : false,
    "autoUpdatePackage" : false,
    "checkOnly" : false,
    "ignoreWarnings" : false,
    "performRetrieve" : false,
    "purgeOnDelete" : false,
    "rollbackOnError" : false,
    "runTests" : null,
    "singlePackage" : false,
    "testLevel" : "NoTestRun"
    }
}
```

I got the below error.

```
[{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 2000509217-124965 (1608348295)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}]
```

After trying the same request again I got the below error.

```
[{"message":"Deploy options should not be specified for the deploy recent validation request.","errorCode":"ARGUMENT_OBJECT_PARSE_ERROR"}]
```

I upload the same zip file using workbench and the deployment was successful. But with postman I'm not sure how to do it.

please help.

Comment: Any solution found for this?

Comment: @rrc1709 Not yet, have raised a support case with salesforce to know what is going wrong. Will update here if it works